# how to calculate distance between car and next junction in veins

Tags: omnet++, traffic-simulation

using *getCurrentPosition()* method gives the current coordinates of the car and *getJunctionPosition()* gives the the coordinates of a node.
but base on calculating distance of the car to the next junction and evaluating results i belives these cordinates are of different format( once sumo coordinates and other is omnet coordinates) so whats the best way to calculate the distance of car to next junction.
second question is about the exit time of cars, how we can notify when a car left simulation and record the time when this happend

Comment: Which version of Veins are you using?

Comment: dear @ChristophSommer: i use  veins 3.0  -  omnet 4.6 - sumo 0.21.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veins distinguishes between coordinates of type `Coord` (which represent OMNeT++ coordinates) and those of type `TraCICoord` (which represent TraCI/SUMO coordinates). Because their transformation depends on the running simulation, it offers API calls to convert between them. The API calls to convert between `TraCICoord` and `Coord` are called [`omnet2traci`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h#L113) and `traci2omnet`.

You are right: In Veins 3.0, the [`getJunctionPosition` API call](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L64) returns a `TraCICoord`, hence you will need to call `traci2omnet` to convert this to a `Coord`, on which you can then call [`.distance(Coord)`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/inet/Coord.h#L173).

Note that (because this was such a common operation) in Veins 4a2, the [`Junction::getPosition` API call](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L178) directly returns a `Coord`.

Comment: glad to hear that. I notice that your question actually includes another one. Could you kindly open a new question to ask this? This will ensure that visitors to this site can easily find the right question for their problem.