# How to get the coordinate of next junction in Veins 5.2

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm new to Omnetpp and Veins.
I'm triyng to write an application modifyng the existing TraciDemo11p application in Veins.
Now I'm stuck since I don't know how to get the coordinate of the next junction for the vehicle.
I saw this:
[how to calculate distance between car and next junction in veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187310/how-to-calculate-distance-between-car-and-next-junction-in-veins)

since it is what I need, but it is really old (Veins 3) and I saw the interface are changed.

I tried to serch online without good results.
I also saw that in the TraciCommandInterface there is this part of code:

```
// Junction methods
    std::list<std::string> getJunctionIds();
    class VEINS_API Junction {
    public:
        Junction(TraCICommandInterface* traci, std::string junctionId)
            : traci(traci)
            , junctionId(junctionId)
        {
            connection = &traci->connection;
        }

        Coord getPosition();
        std::list<Coord> getShape();

    protected:
        TraCICommandInterface* traci;
        TraCIConnection* connection;
        std::string junctionId;
    };
    Junction junction(std::string junctionId)
    {
        return Junction(this, junctionId);
    }
```

I think that what I need is to call the getPosition() method, but I don't know how since I think I have to refer to the next junction object.
How to do this? Thank you.

Thanks